# Gluon Mobile Scrollable Dropdown Button

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Is there a way to make the dropdown button contents scrollable? I  have a lot of menu items that extend the dropdown list beyond the screen of the device.

```
try {
        DropdownButton merchantChooser = (DropdownButton) this.view.lookup("#review-merchant-chooser");
        VBox container = (VBox) this.view.lookup("#review-container");
        TextArea area = (TextArea) this.view.lookup("#review-text");
        StackPane sp = (StackPane) this.view.lookup("#review-wrapper");
        Button btn = (Button) this.view.lookup("#review-submit");

        Utility.setBackground(sp, Utility.bannerImg2);
        Utility.setFadedBackground(true, container);

        merchantChooser.getItems().clear();
        if (MainView.merchants.isInitialized()) {
            btn.setDisable(false);
            MenuItem firstItem = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < MainView.merchants.size(); i++) {
                Label label = new Label(MainView.merchants.get(i).getName());
                label.setWrapText(true);
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem(label.getText());

                merchantChooser.getItems().add(item);

                if(i == 0)
                    firstItem = item;
            }

            merchantChooser.setSelectedItem(firstItem);
            merchantChooser.setPrefWidth(200);
        }
        else
        {
            btn.setDisable(true);
        }

        btn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            //ENTER BACKEND POST HERE TO SEND REVIEW TO DATABASE!!
        });

    } catch (NullPointerException nex) {
        System.out.println("Null pointer at AddReviewView");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Other exception in discount view");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have many items, maybe the `DropdownButton` is not the best control for the job. It doesn't provide a way to make it scrollable.

You can have a look at other options, like the `PopupView` [control](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/PopupView.html).

This control allows custom content, so you can add a `ScrollPane` with a `VBox` that will contain all the items. Instead of `MenuItem` controls, you can use regular `Button` ones.

This is a quick implementation, but it is also styled as the `DropdownButton`.

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    Button button = new Button("Click me", new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_DROP_DOWN));
    button.getStyleClass().add("flat");
    button.setStyle("-fx-border-color: lightgray; -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0");
    button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

    PopupView popup = new PopupView(button);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Button item = new Button("item " + i);
        item.setPrefWidth(100);
        item.getStyleClass().add("flat");
        item.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("item " + item.getText());
            popup.hide();
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(item);
    }
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vBox);
    scrollPane.setMaxHeight(200);
    scrollPane.setPrefWidth(110);

    popup.setContent(scrollPane);

    button.setOnAction(event -> popup.show());

    setCenter(button);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had found that (on android) it is next to impossible for a user to scroll in javafx ComboBox (without selecting an item). Your answer helped me to develop a scrollable ComboBox.

Comment: How can I do this in Scene Builder?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson What exactly do you want to do? The whole custom `PopupView` control is attached to a button, this is the one that you can define in FXML. The rest will be done by code. Anyway, better to ask a new question with more details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JoséPereda I want to select time. I have looked at JFoenix, but it gives me null pointer exceptions when I look with `adb` while pressing `JFXDatePicker`. It was just a test. Notice that JFoenix have `TimePicker`.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson And what does that have to do with this question?? Post another one please.